# JPA 2.0 : what is javax.validation.* package?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations, jpa-2.0

What is the [`javax.validation`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/package-summary.html) package in [Java EE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html)? How to use this with [JPA](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html)?

I want to validate my JPA [Entity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Entity.html) with the [`@NotNull`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) annotation. My JPA implementation is [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/).

Here's my Entity:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable , EmployeeDetail {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private long salary;
    ...
```

Comment: Bean Validation Api: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

Comment: @Adrian repost as an answer

Comment: @Adrian Ensure you summarise the contents of the link if you post an answer.

Comment: if this is bean validation , then how to use with JPA 2.0 ?

Comment: @Harmeet Singh JPA 2 just supports Bean Validation out of the box.

Comment: where i will find the example of implement this validation ?

Answer (score 16):

Using the Bean Validation Api you can quite easy ensure standard validation (not null, patterns, email) on your entities (or beans in common).

Check out Oracles tutorials for Bean Validation Api: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html

Also Hibernate should be no problem with this, as it is the reference implementation: http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

For a good introduction check Hibernates tutorial on this topic: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/

Some other tutorials (Google for JPA 2 + Bean Validation)

- http://www.jboss.org/jdf/examples/ticket-monster/tutorial/DataPersistence/
- http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.de/2010/01/jpa-2-and-bean-validation-in-action.html

JSR specifications…

- Bean Validation 1.1:

  - [spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/)
  - [JSR 349](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349)
- Bean Validation 1.0

  - [JSR 303](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)

Comment: where i find the example to implement validation with JPA 2.0 ?

Comment: @Harmeet Singh Check the introduction over at Hibernate. For the beginning you can simple add the included annotations on your entities.